# Qt List Widget dynamic content loading when scroll

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, scroll, qwidget

I would like to create a widget for Qt (not QML) which derives from, for example, QListWidget, and loads the content dynamically when scrolling up/down, as most of Android/iOS applications does.

Does anybody know which is the best approach?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading the content dynamically doesn't mean it's infinite. For that, just implement a model's fetchMore() and canFetchMore() methods.

Comment: Hi peppe. Thanks for your answer, I will test it in the next week and I will text you again. Have a nice weekend,

Comment: It works just for end of the list not start of the list (just scroll down not scroll up). What idea do you have about up-ward scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

The fetchMore and canFetchMore is really slick, but it kind of obscures how things work a bit.

A more direct approach you could just use this function inside your sub-classed QListWidget.

```
void MyQListWidgetClass::scrollContentsBy(int dx, int dy)
{
    QListWidget::scrollContentsBy(dx, dy);

    bool scrolled_top = false;
    if(this->verticalScrollBar()->value() == this->verticalScrollBar()->minimum())
        scrolled_top = true;

    bool scrolled_bottom = false;
    if(this->verticalScrollBar()->value() == this->verticalScrollBar()->maximum())
        scrolled_bottom = true;


    if(scrolled_top)
        qDebug() << "FIRE FIRE FIRE FIRE!!!";

    if(scrolled_bottom)
        qDebug() << "WATER WATER WATER WATER!!!";
}
```

Of course if you wanted to add more padding you could subtract some from the min/max values.